# efficient method to scale down 32 bit number to a 16 bit number

Tags: c, arm

I'm trying to scale down a 32 bit value to a signed 16bit number (uint32_t -> int16_t), or in other words trying to scale down my uin32_t result to scale between 0 and 32767(int16_max). My code looks like this. In this snippet, my input range happens to be 0 to 90000. So an input of 90000 should correspond to 32767, and so on:

```
    uint16_t scaled_estimate = 0;
    uint32_t input = 85000;
    uint32_t max_base = 90000;
    uint16_t new_base = INT16_MAX; // 32767
    uint16_t scaled_estimate = (input * new_base) / max_base;
    if(scaled_estimate > new_base) scaled_estimate = new_base; // clamp
```

Is there a better way to achieve this scaling on embedded platforms or should I trust the compiler to do the right thing?

Comment: "esp ones without a floating point unit" - there doesn't seem to be any floating-point math involved

Comment: if input is actually 32 bit unsigned, then you can do `input>>17` to scale it down to 15 bit (16 bit signed positives)

Comment: so `input * new_base` can already overflow a 32 bit int. Cast one of the terms to a 64 bit integer just to make sure it doesn't happen

Comment: `new_base` should be `uint32_t` since it's going to be promoted anyways. And you should clamp the `input`, not the output, e.g. `if (input > max_base) {scaled_estimate = new_base; } else {/* compute scaled_estimate */}`

Comment: @ForceBru: In general, the fact there is no floating-point arithmetic in a current solution to some problem does not mean a better solution would not use floating-point arithmetic, especially if hardware were available.

Comment: @Jean-FrançoisFabre no need to do 64-bit arithmetic. If `input*(uint32_t)new_base/(uint32_t)new_base!=input`, you've hit the wraparound. And since the arithmetic in this expression is unsigned, the behavior and result are completely standard-defined.